# Show base currency price & display currency price at the same time in magento2?

Tags: magento2, price, currency, multicurrency

I would like to show product price in both base currency & display currency. I have already enable display currency in frontend - that is i can see "USD / EUR" in header dropdown.

If i want to show 2 price, one in base currency, one in display currency at the same time, what should be the correct way?

Basic currency in the store, USD. Frontend currency displayed in EUR, I just need to add to the current price, the original price (USD).

I tried to change **final_price.html**

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.html
```

This part of the code

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount() , [
        'price_id' => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type' => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]);
    ?>
```

But I get only the displayed price (EUR) or empty space without any errors.

I can get the main price (USD) using this code,

```
<?php if ($priceAmount = $block->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()):?>
    <span> / $ <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $priceAmount ?> </span>
<?php endif;?>
```

But only in **atribute.phtml**

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/atribute.html
```

Now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzn4a.png

I would like to display: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srQzK.png

Magento 2.2.4